# Primary key from left join

Tags: mysql, database

My doubt raises after i did this:

```
select name
from Highschooler
where ID in(select Friend.ID2
            from Highschooler left join Friend
            on Friend.ID1 = '1911' or Friend.ID1 = '1689');
```

The tables can be found [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/db/asset/socialdata.html)

**The expected result was correct**, and respects this clause:
Find the names of all students who are friends with someone named Gabriel.

Notice that i did not make any reference to the table **Highschooler.ID**

This seemed intuitive to me but then it got me thinking as Highschooler table does not have ID selected as primary key in my workbench.

So, when doing a left join, how does mysql know that i want to pair ID from highschooler with a column from Friend? **The tables don't have any column name in common.** So for all i know sql could try to pair grade from Highschooler, with ID1 from Friend.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And your left join does not have joining condition between two tables.

Comment: @Viki888 I am sorry, i added more info.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that MySQL does not know how to join tables. You have to tell MySQL how to join the tables. In case of an outer join, use the `on` clause. However, in this particular case you do not need an outer join, since you want ids from the friend table.

Comment: But why did mysql decided to use Highschooler.ID to pair with Friend?
I never made a reference to ID

Comment: MySQL creates a Cartesian join in the absence of a real join condition.